# What do external_attr and internal_attr refer to in ZipInfo?

Tags: python, zip

I don't see the explanation of what `external_attr` and `internal_attr` actually refer to (in both python2 and python3 if there is any difference).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Could anybody provide any details?

Answer (score 0):

This one was interesting, the source code didn't make it obvious either but digging into the book [*Python Essential Reference*](https://www.dabeaz.com/per.html) by the prominent python developer David Beazley.

`internal_attr` Describes the internal structure of the archive contents. If the low-order bit is 1, the data is ASCII text. Otherwise, binary data is assumed.
`external_attr`  External file attributes which are operating system dependent.

Comment: I use internal_attr=1 to test for file. Could this cause any problems in some cases? What is the correct way to test for a file?

Comment: @user1424739 It should indicate that the content's is ASCII-text files, if it's binary data you should probably use 0 some other bit.

Comment: How to determine whether it is a file or a directory?

Comment: There's an `is_dir` function for that purpose https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.is_dir

Answer (score 0):

The [PKZIP Application Note](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) (referenced in [Python docs for zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)) state the following:

```
4.4.15 external file attributes: (4 bytes)

    The mapping of the external attributes is
    host-system dependent (see 'version made by').  For
    MS-DOS, the low order byte is the MS-DOS directory
    attribute byte.  If input came from standard input, this
    field is set to zero.
```

```
4.4.14 internal file attributes: (2 bytes)

    Bits 1 and 2 are reserved for use by PKWARE.

    4.4.14.1 The lowest bit of this field indicates, if set, 
    that the file is apparently an ASCII or text file.  If not
    set, that the file apparently contains binary data.
    The remaining bits are unused in version 1.0.

    4.4.14.2 The 0x0002 bit of this field indicates, if set, that 
    a 4 byte variable record length control field precedes each 
    logical record indicating the length of the record. The 
    record length control field is stored in little-endian byte
    order.  This flag is independent of text control characters, 
    and if used in conjunction with text data, includes any 
    control characters in the total length of the record. This 
    value is provided for mainframe data transfer support.
```